# AmCharts4 - Unable to load file

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I'm showing a chart using AmCharts4 with the URL option to load the data from a PHP file in JSON format. The problem is that sometimes I have an error. In the javascript console, I see the message: `net::ERR_NETWORK_IO_SUSPENDED` and in the chart the message: `Unable to load file`. I need to reload the page to load the chart again. I'm not able to find a similar problem on the web, therefore I would be very grateful for help.

```
const chartTotales = am4core.create('chart-disponibilidad-pastel', am4charts.PieChart);

chartTotales.dataSource.url = 'backend/production.php?opc=4';
chartTotales.dataSource.reloadFrequency = 6000;

const pieSeries = chartTotales.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = 'horas';
pieSeries.dataFields.category = 'tipo';
pieSeries.dataFields.test = '0 min';
pieSeries.slices.template.stroke = am4core.color('#fff');
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 1;

pieSeries.labels.template.text = '{category} {test} {value.formatDuration(\'hh:mm:ss\')} Hrs';
pieSeries.slices.template.tooltipText = '{category} {value.formatDuration(\'hh:mm:ss\')}';

const colorSetTotal = new am4core.ColorSet();
//D72906
colorSetTotal.list = ['#F6F623', '#498561', '#D72906'].map( function(color) {
  // @ts-ignore
  return new am4core.color(color);
});
```

[image: Chart error]

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting updateCurrentData to true, this shouldn't remove current data.

```
chartTotales.dataSource.updateCurrentData= true;
```

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/datasource/#updateCurrentData_property

Also check Network tab in browser tools to see what is in response from API.
Maybe you are hitting rate limiter.